# how to select markers in the polygon from mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i'm saving markers coordinates in mysql like below image

[image]

what i need is when user draw on maps like below image

[image]

i could get the shape and select markers in the shape from mysql and create a query.
for example: 

$query= mysql_query("SELECT `location` FROM table WHERE Coordinates in the polygon");

i belive i need use ajax. and i'm using google maps v3
is this even possible to do that ?
PLEASE HELP, Any idea that i could somthing like that other way ??

Comment: How you have stored the polygon shape in db.. you use geometry POLYGON data Type ? or store the coord .in others way?  and what do you mean for 'location' ?

Comment: @scaisEdge i saved my coordinates in `location` col in mysql db and i need to find this locations by drawing polygon on the map

Comment: OK  .. but  if which data type / format  you save location coordinates .. ?   ..and you know and want use mysql geometry extension or not ?

Comment: @scaisEdge which data/ type is better ? i'm currently using varchar(256) to save coordinates , and if geometry extention works i'm okay with it but i don't know how to use it ... please help

Comment: I have update the answer .. hope is useful ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps does not provide GIS functions to select the coordinates inside a polygon. You could do using the spatial extension ( data type GEOMETRY) for mysql .. and for this you can go into that ..http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html  for mysql doc.

A simple way to select locations (points) in google maps is to use the extreme values of the coordinates of the polygon points to get the equivalent to the coordinates of the rectangle that contains the polygon vertices and then perform a select

```
  select location  
  from my_table 
  where location_lat >= minLat_polygon
  AND location_lat  <=  maxLat_poligon
  AND location_lng  <=  maxLng_polygon
  AND location_lng  >=  minLng_polygon
```

Comment: also keep in mind that simple way will not work properly for concave shaped polygons

Comment: @Ergec   if you use  the min e and the max for lat and the min and  the max for lng should work (obtain the mbr vertex)